# Retrieve bundle class instance from a compiler pass

Tags: php, symfony

I'm not sure to find any solution here, as [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852611/symfony2-access-kernel-from-a-compiler-pass) as already been asked but give a (working) solution that I can't implement, because I'm working on the symfony [FrameworkBundle](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/18579) (for a [bugfix](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/18563)).

**Situation**

In a compiler pass (or a bundle extension), I need to get the path to load resources of each bundle of the application (3rd party included, all bundles registered in the Kernel).

For now, I use the following in a bundle extension where the ContainerBuilder is accessible:

```
foreach ($container->getParameter('kernel.bundles') as $bundle) {
    // Create a reflection from the FQCN of the bundle class
    $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($bundle);
    // Localise the file containing the class
    $path = dirname($reflection->getFilename());

    // Do stuffs that load files such as $path/Resources/config/serializer.yml
}
```

Every bundle class has a `getPath()` method that can return a custom path in case of custom directory structure.

So, use the reflection file could lead to ignore some configuration files instead of load them properly.

**Wrong alternative**

Create an instance of the bundle and invoke the `getPath()` method, could be:

```
$reflection = new \ReflectionClass($bundle);
$getPathReflection = new \ReflectionMethod($bundle, 'getPath');
$path = $getPathReflection->invoke(new $bundle());
```

But what about if one of the bundle classes take one (or more) constructor arguments?
This would lead to a fatal error.

**Problem**

So, I can't create the instances manually because I don't have the knowledge of what they need to be instantiated.

My first thought was that I can get the `kernel` service then loop over `$kernel->getBundles()` and call the `getPath()` method.

But the result of `$container->get('kernel')` is:

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\RuntimeException]
>   You have requested a synthetic service ("kernel"). The DIC does not know how to construct this service.

Is there a way to call this method for each bundle class in a compiler pass/bundle extension without adding an argument to the FrameworkBundle class?

**EDIT**

First possible alternative:

```
$getPathReflection = new \ReflectionMethod($bundle, 'getPath');
$reflectionInstance = $reflection->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();
$path = $getPathReflection->invoke($reflectionInstance) ?: dirname($reflection->getFilename());
```

**cons:**

- `\ReflectionClass::newInstanceWithoutConstructor()` is available since PHP 5.4 only, so the tests don't pass.
- In case of the `Bundle#getPath()` value depends on constructor arguments, this would leads to `null`, and so to use the reflection path (i.e. `?: dirname($reflection->getFilename())`).

Comment: To follow the PR advancing: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/18579